# Problem with autoresizing when iPhone is rotated

Tags: iphone, rotation, autoresize

In my iPhone app, I have a view (let's call it RectangleView) within the content view that I'd like to scale, along with all its subviews, when the iPhone is rotated. So, when the phone is rotated from landscape to portrait mode, I'd like RectangleView (and all its subviews) to keep their original shape and position relative to each other, but just get smaller. I am using autoresizing on it and all its subviews in Interface Builder to try and do this.

Now here's the problem. When the phone is rotated, all of RectangleView's subviews scale and move relative to the entire content view, not relative their parent view (which is RectangleView). This is a problem because the content view is now a different shape (portrait) than it was before (landscape), and so all the elements on the screen are in the wrong places, when they should just be scaled down within RectangleView. And I am confused because some of these elements even move out of RectangleView, which I didn't even know was possible since they are supposed to be contained within RectangleView.

Can anyone explain what might be happening here, and how I can just scale RectangleView and all its subviews to retain their original shape and positions, but just on a smaller scale?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that they are moving out of the RectangleView, and it isn't that the RectangleView is resizing and filling the content area? Also, I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I found that I needed to call `[view setNeedsDisplay]` after rotation to make my custom view work properly.

Comment: Yeah, I made sure that they really are moving outside of the RectangleView, and that the RectangleView retains its original shape... And, I called each of RectangleView's subviews after the resizing to confirm that they really are subviews of RectangleView, and they are. They just somehow move out of RectangleView.

Also, I tried calling [RectangleView setNeedsDisplay], but it only made the RectangleView resize itself to fill the content area.